# Search viewed questions

Tags: support, search

I'd like to read a question that I viewed yesterday. Unfortunately I do not remember the exact words used in the question or answers. I only know what was written in the question conceptually. I tried all the search options including advance search in SO. The only remaining option is to go through viewed questions. I can see that those questions are in a different color. But not sure how to search all of them by date.

So my question is,
Is there any way to search the questions that I previously viewed?

Answer (score 7):

Good question, but that would involve tracking which links you clicked which I don't think SO does.

Which browser are you using?

If you're using Chrome (for example) you can click on History (Ctrl+H) and see all the links you've clicked on for the last few days. Firefox (Ctrl+Shift+H) and IE also keep a history.

Comment: Chrome in Mac. Unfortunately the history was already cleared. Anyway thank you @ChrisF.

Comment: Of course you can always ask the ever-helpful folks at NSA for your browsing history :P

Answer (score 3):

You could try to enter those words you remember in the "New Question" field. When you click on the body, a list of potentially related questions appears and may include the one you search. Heaven knows why this potential-duplicate search sometimes works better...

Comment: I have noticed the same thing. I tried there before asked this question in meta. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you did anything on the post, like commenting, voting, etc, you should be able to see it back in the all actions tab or the votes tab on your user profile. A keyword might help in a browser-based search.

If that doesn't help, maybe your browser history can be of help.